# How to update an array and pull a nested element from same array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

With the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "firstArray" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "456",
            "status" : "open",
            "nestedArray" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "100",
                    "quantity" : 10
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "101",
                    "quantity" : 10
                }, 
                {
                   "_id" : "102",
                    "quantity" : 10
                }
         },
 
        {
            "_id" : "789",
            "status" : "open",
            "nestedArray" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "200",
                    "quantity" : 10
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "201",
                    "quantity" : 10
                }, 
                {
                   "_id" : "202",
                    "quantity" : 10
                }
         }
     ]
}
```

How can I update the quantity by 20 of the nested ID 101 element and pull the one with the ID 201 from the same MongoDB query ?

I am trying to do that in Java with $set and $pull operator and I'm stuck with the following error:

> [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=40, message='Update created a conflict
> at 'firstArray.0.nestedArray'', details={}}]

Comment: Where did `firstArray.0.nestedArray` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn’t allow multiple operations on the same property in the same update call. This means that the two operations must happen in two individual queries.

1. The first solution is you can write 2 seperate queries for both the operations.
2. The second solution is you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `firstArray`
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `nestedArray` and remove `_id: "201"` record
- `$map` to iterate loop of above filtered `nestedArray`
- `$cond` check condition if `_id: "101"` then return new `quantity` otherwise return current
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with updated properties

```
db.collection.update(
  { "firstArray.nestedArray._id": "101" },
  [{
    $set: {
      firstArray: {
        $map: {
          input: "$firstArray",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                nestedArray: {
                  $map: {
                    input: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$$this.nestedArray",
                        cond: { $ne: ["$$this._id", "201"] }
                      }
                    },
                    in: {
                      _id: "$$this._id",
                      quantity: {
                        $cond: [
                          { $eq: ["$$this._id", "101"] },
                          20,
                          "$$this.quantity"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HaLucxIjsrF)

Comment: your 2nd solution seems to be great but I found it very difficult to maintain, probably because I've simplified my data to the purpose of the question. I'll go for the 1st one and begin with the pulls operation as these pull are our first priorities.